# Customize <header> in category page

Tags: customization, content

I'm working in a blog with a template of my own. When I link to a category page (i.e. `mydomain.com/category/mycategory`) Wordpress generates this HTML code just after the `header.php`:

```
<!-- HTML rendered by header.php -->

<!-- This 2 lines belong to index.php -->
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

<!-- HTML rendered by content.php -->
<header class="page-header">
  <h1 class="page-title">Category: My Category</h1>
</header>
<!-- .page-header --> <!-- this comment is also generated by content.php -->
<div id="post-292" class="grid-item">
  <!-- The rest of content.php -->
</div>
```

My `content.php` file is as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template part for displaying content
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Sixteen
 * @since Twenty Sixteen 1.0
 */
?>

<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="grid-item">
...
```

So the question is: where is the `<header>` tag generated and how can I customize it? I want to change the `<h1>` rendered content *Category: My Category* to be just *My Category*, for example.

Any help or guide is appreciated. Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: 1) You might want to review the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category). 2) Could you post your `header.php` and possibly your `index.php`

Comment: WordPress works with themes and the themes are responsible for generating the html code. So a theme is activated and you want to override some template parts. To do that you have to create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Comment: @GregMcMullen I've been reading the template hierachy and `content.php` is never mentioned. I added a `category.php` file in the same directory as `index.php` and now is reading that file. Could you post your comment as an answer? That's exactly what I needed and you gave me an excellent reference bibliography. Thank you so much.

Comment: @AlvaroPedraza The comment that Greg provided solved your answer?

Comment: @AlvaroPedraza I've added and updated my answer for you.

Comment: checkout category.php or archive.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Review the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#category) from the Codex to gain a better understanding of what files are read when. This will help you to understand what's called in what situation (tag/category/front-page/etc).

Content.php is never mentioned in the documentation as its not a part of the template hierarchy. Theme developers will use different file names and will reference them within the loop.

Most of the themes by Automattic use this technique to call the various parts to build out the content. Review your `index.php`, `page.php`, or `post.php` to see if `content.php` is used there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create another file form `header.php` and name it like `header-{category-name}.php`.
2. Do your needed change on `header-{category-name}.php`.
3. Then in your `category.php` call this file by `get_header( 'category-name' )`.
4. If you don't have `category.php` file then create one by copying the `archive.php` template then follow the above instruction.

Follow those above steps and you'll get your desired result.